# Curious exception propagation to main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, future, runnable

In the following case, why is it that both exceptions get propagated to the main thread?

(This is a test which I have configured to throw a runtime exception when stop() is called):

```
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    futures.add(executorService.submit(runnable1));
    futures.add(executorService.submit(runnable2));
    Thread.sleep(1000L); // wait for runnables to run for a while
    runnable2.stop();
    runnable1.stop();

    for (Future future : futures) {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred");
        }
    }
```

I would expect only the first to be propagated as the second is swallowed with this setup (due to it waiting on the first runnable by looping through the array list in order).

An example of this swallowing can be seen if we only call runnable2.stop() - in this case there is nothing displayed at all.

Why is the exception for runnable2 printed at all?

I should also mention that when stop() is called on each thread, there is a pause inside the method before it throws the exception to allow for the futures loop to still be invoked.

Comment: I don't see why the second exception would not be kept

Comment: By the time you get to the loop, both tasks have completed. So why do you expect one to be swallowed?

Comment: @MauricePerry because we are waiting for runnable1 to finish first due to the nature of the loop. If I call stop only on the second thread with this setup, nothing is displayed at all. If I do the same thing with the first thread, we see an exception and it begins to wait on the second.

Comment: But here you stopped them both. So both are complete, so there is no waiting.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Sorry, I didn't mention this test is configured to pause in each thread when stop() is called before it finishes. Test it out and you'll observe the same behaviour.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and turn this into a proper [mcve]. That is, don't let us guess what happens when `stop()` is called.

Comment: Why are you using raw types? `Future<T>` is generic.

Comment: I assume that if you only call `stop()` on the second one then the loop waits forever for the first one to complete? That doesn't mean the exception has been swallowed, that just means your program has hung.

Comment: IMHO, a Future handles exceptions the same way as the result: it keeps a reference to it until another thread calls .get(); then the exception is rethrown.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks David, that answers it. I'm using a CompletionService, however, I was curious as to why this use case seemed to behave the way it did. Post the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only call `stop()` on the second one then the `for` loop waits forever for the first one to complete. The exception hasn't been swallowed; it has been captured and will be thrown if and when your program calls `get()` on the second future, but your program has hung waiting for the first future and will not reach that point.

Answer (score 0):

> In the following case, why is it that both exceptions get propagated to the main thread?

That is the nature of the `Future` class.  It wraps your job so regardless of the order of the jobs being executed and finishing, it will return the results or throw an exception when you call `future.get()`.

So if the 2nd job throws an exception first, it gets stored in the `Future` associated with the job so it can be returned when you go through the `futures` list later on, even though the first `future.get()` might have to wait for the 1st job to finish.

You can take a look at the code for `FutureTask` if you'd like.  Here are some snippets:

```
public void run() {
  ...
            try {
                // Gray: this calls your job, storing the result
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                // this puts ex into result and sets the state to EXCEPTIONAL
                setException(ex);
            }
```

Then:

```
public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
   ...

    Object x = outcome;
    if (s == NORMAL)
        return (V)x;
    if (s >= CANCELLED)
        throw new CancellationException();
    throw new ExecutionException((Throwable)x);
```

So when the run finishes either the result of the `call()` method or the resulting exception is stored in `outcome` along with a `state` which can be `NORMAL` or `EXCEPTIONAL`.